# Apply CSS Class to Component tag

Tags: angular, angular7

I have the angular component (simplified version):

```
export class HeaderMainComponent { }
```

With the HTML:

```
<header>

  <nav>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
  </nav>

</header>
```

And I use it as follows:

```
<header-main class="dark"></header-main>
```

How to apply `dark` css class of header-main to header tag?

```
<header class="dark">
```

Is this possible without using a variable in the component?

Comment: css: `header-main header { color: red }` or if you're using sass `header-main header { @extend .dark }`or in the component with sass `:host { header { @extend .dark }}`

Comment: So you’re trying to pass a class to the elements within the component from the component tag only?

Comment: @BenSteward I only need to change the styling of header tag based on the css class applied to header-main

Comment: My answer should work for you then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header-main [classes]="'dark other-class'"></header-main>
```

In header-main.ts:

```
@Input('classes') classes: string;
```

In header-main.html:

```
<header class="{{classes}}"></header>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that option ... What is why I asked: "Is this possible without using a variable in the component?"

Comment: You’re trying to dynamically apply a class to another element through a parent element. I don’t think that’s possible without some kind of variable. Why do you need to avoid variables?